# javax.servlet.ServletException: Exception: java.lang.Exception: Failed to create DBConnectionPool

Tags: java, database, connection, weblogic

Hi I am encountering this error when I am deploying a war file or exploded file in weblogic

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Exception: java.lang.Exception: Failed to create
DBConnectionPool
```

This is the command to my cmd

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>java weblogic.Deployer -adminurl localho
st:7001 -username exakt -password 1qaz2wsx -name yellowfin123 -deploy e:war/yell
owfin123.war
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup the data source in weblogic for whatever database your app is using?

Comment: Log in to the weblogic admin console and see if you have Data Sources present (assuming your app is using them via jndi).